# Setting seconds to 00 in @DateTime.UtcNow in datetime-local

Tags: javascript

I have the following in a view cshtml of a MVC

```
    <dt>Start Date (UTC)</dt>
    <input type="datetime-local"
           id="startDate"
           name="startDate"
           value="@DateTime.UtcNow"
           min="2023-06-07T00:00"
           max="2099-06-14T00:00" />
```

How to I do it so that the seconds in the @DateTime.UtcNow defaults to 0 or a value of 0 seconds is accepted as currently if i put in time of 2023-06-07 14:30:22 it complains (Please enter a valid date) about the seconds being 22, it needs to be 00, but I'm not sure where this value of 00 is coming from?

I have also tried this with no success:

```
value="@DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm[00]")"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the line following successfully:

```
<dd><input type="datetime" value="@DateTime.UtcNow" name="startDate" /></dd>
```